# Ref.get() does not work if comes from a just loaded List<Ref<?>>

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'm going crazy with Objectify because i've a problem with a `List<Ref<?>>` like this:

`@Index
@Load
private LinkedList<Ref<Post>> diary = new LinkedList<Ref<Post>>();`

when i save this `Profile` entity the `diary` Ref list is ok, and this:
`getDiary().get(0).get()` give me the correct `Post` entity.

When i load both `Profile` and then the first `Post` like this:
`ofy().load().key(myProfileKey).get().getDiary().get(0).get()` which should load the first `Post` in list, i got `null`, even if the `Profile` and the `diary` are correctly loaded (`diary` contains the correct `Ref<Post>`).

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
In my previous question i forgot to tell that `Post` has a `@Parent` field: the `Profile`.
Removing `@Parent` all works... even if i don't understand why.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a test case?  Also, what version of Ofy4 are you using?  This situation is covered by existing tests, so I'm not sure what is going on.

Comment: Also - this code is impossible.  `ofy().load().type(...).key(...)` won't compile because there is no key() method on the command object that comes back from type().

Comment: I was confused a lot: .type(...) token was not.
Objectify v4.0a4.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I reduced all to a TestCase:

```java
public class StandaloneTestCase {

    protected static LocalServiceTestHelper helper = null;
    protected static Objectify ds = null;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig config = new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig();
        helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(config);
        helper.setUp();
        ds = ObjectifyService.ofy();

        ObjectifyService.register(Post.class);
        ObjectifyService.register(Profile.class);
    }


    @Test
    public void test() {
        Profile p = new Profile();
        p.setEmail("user1@email.com");
        p.setPassword("user1pwd");
        p.setRegistrationDate(new Date(0L));
        p.setSex("Male");
        p.setName("Name1");
        p.setSurname("Surname1");
        p.setFullName("Name1 Nick1 Surname1");
        Key<Profile> pKey = ds.save().entity(p).now();

        Profile pro = ds.load().type(Profile.class).filter("name", "Name1").first().get();
        Assert.assertEquals(0, ds.load().key(pro.getRef().getKey()).get().getFriends().size());

        Post newPost = new Post();
        newPost.setDate(new Date());
        newPost.setTitle("New Post p1");
        newPost.setDescription("New Descr p1");
        newPost.setAuthor(pro.getRef());

        ds.save().entity(newPost).now();
        Ref<Post> postRef = newPost.getRef();

        pro.getDiary().addFirst(postRef);
        pro.getMessages().addFirst(postRef);
        ds.save().entity(pro).now();

        newPost.getReceivers().addAll(pro.getFriends());

        Collection<Profile> friends = ds.load().refs(pro.getFriends()).values(); 
        for (Profile friend : friends) {
            friend.getMessages().addFirst(newPost.getRef());
        }
        ds.save().entities(friends).now();
        ds.save().entity(newPost).now();

        Assert.assertEquals(1, ds.load().key(pro.getKey()).get().getDiary().size());
        Assert.assertEquals(1, ds.load().key(pro.getKey()).get().getMessages().size());
        Assert.assertEquals(newPost.getRef(), ds.load().key(pro.getKey()).get().getDiary().get(0));
        // BIG FAT WARNING
        Assert.assertEquals(newPost, ds.load().key(pro.getKey()).get().getDiary().get(0).get());
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
        ds.clear();
        helper.tearDown();
    }

}

//

@Entity
class Identifable<T> {

    @Id 
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        return equals((Identifable<?>) obj);
    }

    public boolean equals(Identifable<?> other) {
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}


@Entity @Cache
class Post extends Identifable<Post> {

    @Index(IfNotNull.class)
    @Load
    @Parent
    private Ref<Profile> author = null;

    @Index(IfNotNull.class)
    private Date date = null;

    @Index(IfNotNull.class)
    private String title = null;
    private String description = null;

    @Index(IfNotEmpty.class)
    @Load
    private Set<Ref<Profile>> receivers = new HashSet<Ref<Profile>>();

    public Set<Ref<Profile>> getReceivers() {
        return receivers;
    }

    public Ref<Profile> getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(Ref<Profile> author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Post [author=" + author + ", date=" + date + ", title=" + title
                + ", description=" + description + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + ((author == null) ? 0 : author.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((date == null) ? 0 : date.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((description == null) ? 0 : description.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((title == null) ? 0 : title.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!super.equals(obj))
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Post other = (Post) obj;
        if (author == null) {
            if (other.author != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!author.equals(other.author))
            return false;
        if (date == null) {
            if (other.date != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!date.equals(other.date))
            return false;
        if (description == null) {
            if (other.description != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!description.equals(other.description))
            return false;
        if (title == null) {
            if (other.title != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!title.equals(other.title))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public Key<Post> getKey() {
        return Key.create(Post.class, getId());
    }

    public Ref<Post> getRef() {
        return Ref.create(getKey(), this);
    }


}

//

@Entity @Cache
class Profile extends Identifable<Profile> {

    @Index
    private String email = null;
    @Index
    private String password = null;

    private Date registrationDate = null;

    @Index(IfNotNull.class)
    private String name = null;
    @Index(IfNotNull.class)
    private String surname = null;
    @Index(IfNotNull.class)
    private String fullName = null;

    @Index
    private String sex = null;

    @Index
    private Date dateOfBirth = null;

    @Index(IfNotEmpty.class)
    @Load
    private LinkedList<Ref<Post>> diary = new LinkedList<Ref<Post>>();

    @Index(IfNotEmpty.class)
    @Load
    private Set<Ref<Profile>> friends = new HashSet<Ref<Profile>>();

    @Index(IfNotEmpty.class)
    @Load
    private LinkedList<Ref<Post>> messages = new LinkedList<Ref<Post>>();

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Date getRegistrationDate() {
        return registrationDate;
    }

    public void setRegistrationDate(Date registrationDate) {
        this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }

    public void setSex(String sex) {
        this.sex = sex;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public Set<Ref<Profile>> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }

    public LinkedList<Ref<Post>> getDiary() {
        return diary;
    }

    public LinkedList<Ref<Post>> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Profile [email=" + email + ", password=" + password
                + ", registrationDate=" + registrationDate + ", name=" + name
                + ", surname=" + surname + ", fullName=" + fullName + ", sex="
                + sex + ", dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth + ", diary=" + diary
                + ", friends=" + friends + ", messages=" + messages + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((dateOfBirth == null) ? 0 : dateOfBirth.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((diary == null) ? 0 : diary.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((email == null) ? 0 : email.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((friends == null) ? 0 : friends.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((fullName == null) ? 0 : fullName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((messages == null) ? 0 : messages.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((password == null) ? 0 : password.hashCode());
        result = prime
                * result
                + ((registrationDate == null) ? 0 : registrationDate.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((sex == null) ? 0 : sex.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((surname == null) ? 0 : surname.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Profile other = (Profile) obj;
        if (dateOfBirth == null) {
            if (other.dateOfBirth != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dateOfBirth.equals(other.dateOfBirth))
            return false;
        if (diary == null) {
            if (other.diary != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!diary.equals(other.diary))
            return false;
        if (email == null) {
            if (other.email != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!email.equals(other.email))
            return false;
        if (friends == null) {
            if (other.friends != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!friends.equals(other.friends))
            return false;
        if (fullName == null) {
            if (other.fullName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!fullName.equals(other.fullName))
            return false;
        if (messages == null) {
            if (other.messages != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!messages.equals(other.messages))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (password == null) {
            if (other.password != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!password.equals(other.password))
            return false;
        if (registrationDate == null) {
            if (other.registrationDate != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!registrationDate.equals(other.registrationDate))
            return false;
        if (sex == null) {
            if (other.sex != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!sex.equals(other.sex))
            return false;
        if (surname == null) {
            if (other.surname != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!surname.equals(other.surname))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public Key<Profile> getKey() {
        return Key.create(Profile.class, getId());
    }

    public Ref<Profile> getRef() {
        return Ref.create(getKey(), this);
    }

}
```

I use Objectify 4.0a4 and App Engine SDK 1.7.2
If you try to remove `@Parent` from `author` `Post` field the test is ok.

This may be NOT an Objectify bug (quite sure) and may be a my conceptual error.